# Google Bar Intervals Chart options

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've created a google line intervals chart. An example google provided can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/4tgfzdyj/ I'm trying to convert this to a Bar Intervals chart, some explanation and var options are given here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/intervals

However, I couldn't do it, even with the example Google provided, I can't get the result given in the picture on the link. When I change the var options for Bar intervals chart, a blank page appears. Unfortunately, Google didn't provide a full working code or jsfiddle for this. and I couldn't get it done. I'm missing something probably? A little help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
  var options_bars = {
        title: 'Bars, default',
        curveType: 'function',
        series: [{'color': '#D9544C'}],
        intervals: { style: 'bars' },
        legend: 'none',
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following is a working snippet of the line intervals from the fiddle provided...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'values');
  data.addColumn({id:'i0', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i1', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});

  data.addRows([
      [1, 100, 90, 110, 85, 96, 104, 120],
      [2, 120, 95, 130, 90, 113, 124, 140],
      [3, 130, 105, 140, 100, 117, 133, 139],
      [4, 90, 85, 95, 85, 88, 92, 95],
      [5, 70, 74, 63, 67, 69, 70, 72],
      [6, 30, 39, 22, 21, 28, 34, 40],
      [7, 80, 77, 83, 70, 77, 85, 90],
      [8, 100, 90, 110, 85, 95, 102, 110]]);

  // The intervals data as narrow lines (useful for showing raw source data)
  var options_lines = {
      title: 'Line intervals, default',
      curveType: 'function',
      lineWidth: 4,
      intervals: { 'style':'line' },
      legend: 'none'
  };

  var chart_lines = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_lines'));
  chart_lines.draw(data, options_lines);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_lines" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

if you want to change to bars, using the following options,

```
var options_bars = {
    title: 'Bars, default',
    curveType: 'function',
    series: [{'color': '#D9544C'}],
    intervals: { style: 'bars' },
    legend: 'none',
};
```

then you also need to change the `draw` statement,
because the new options have a different variable name...

from...

```
  chart_lines.draw(data, options_lines);
```

to...

```
  chart_lines.draw(data, options_bars);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'values');
  data.addColumn({id:'i0', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i1', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
  data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});

  data.addRows([
      [1, 100, 90, 110, 85, 96, 104, 120],
      [2, 120, 95, 130, 90, 113, 124, 140],
      [3, 130, 105, 140, 100, 117, 133, 139],
      [4, 90, 85, 95, 85, 88, 92, 95],
      [5, 70, 74, 63, 67, 69, 70, 72],
      [6, 30, 39, 22, 21, 28, 34, 40],
      [7, 80, 77, 83, 70, 77, 85, 90],
      [8, 100, 90, 110, 85, 95, 102, 110]]);

  // The intervals data as narrow lines (useful for showing raw source data)
  var options_bars = {
      title: 'Bars, default',
      curveType: 'function',
      series: [{'color': '#D9544C'}],
      intervals: { style: 'bars' },
      legend: 'none',
  };

  var chart_lines = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_lines'));
  chart_lines.draw(data, options_bars);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_lines" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```